# How to uninstall VMware tools for VMware Workstation 16 Pro VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows 8 VM in my VMware Workstation 16 Pro.

I want to uninstall the VMware Tools from the VM.<sup>1</sup>

I found [this page](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2010137) that claims to explain how to do this, but my version of VMware Workstation has no "Install VMware Tools" option anywhere in the menu bar menus.

I tried uninstalling the VMware tools from Programs and Features in the Control Panel, but that crashed my VM, and then I was unable to login to my VM on the next boot (it kept saying the password was incorrect), and I was forced to destroy that VM and create a new one.

How can I correctly uninstall VMware tools from my VMware Windows VM?

<sup>1</sup>*I need to uninstall the VMware Tools because that is a requirement [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#prepare-vm-image) for importing a VM to AWS.*

Comment: Try stopping the VMware Tools Service and then see if Tools can be properly uninstalled.

Comment: Also in the (many) years I have used VMware, I have not seen a need for "no tools" .  Accordingly, you may wish to ask AWS support and VMware support if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: @John, your suggestion to stop the VMware Tools service before uninstalling worked (I was able to complete the install, and after rebooting, I was able to login to the VM). If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to uninstall VMware tools for VMware Workstation 16 Pro VM

One way to uninstall VMware Tools is to stop the VMware Tools Service (Task Manager, Services) before trying to uninstall.

Then, with the Service stopped, use the VMware Documentation to uninstall  (run Tools Setup64.exe /c) and complete the uninstall.